# Advanced Amazon search on best seller categories

Tags: search, amazon-advertising-api

As an Amazon seller I do lots of research on items to sell. Looking for a way to search on Amazon in different departments for best sellers either programmatically or by other means. For example, under Beauty what are the top sellers for Revlon? You can sort by Relevance, New and Popular, Price, and Avg. Reviews. It would be more helpful to be able to sort by sales volume and/or ranking.

Comment: Please provide more information about what you are trying to achieve. How is this related to development of software?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your best option is the [Product Advertising API](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html). It has undergone a ton of changes over the years though, so it might be tough to find current documentation of all the calls.

This gives you programmatic access to Amazon product metadata ostensibly so one can advertise them.